# Parsing datepicker in jquery

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

In forms I have two inputs for date ,StartDate input and End date input.
I also have datepicker implemented ,

```
 $("#StartDate").datepicker();
```

datepicker formats it something like: 02/27/2013 which I don't like but ok.

I would like to parse date before putting it in serialized array. Is this good aproach and if it is how can I accoplish this?

How to accomplish that End Date inut is bigger than Start That, and not allow the oppsoite file submitting??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', '22/04/2010');
```

Ref: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

Answer (score 3):

Once you set a datepicker, yes it does set the date in plain text, but it also retains the underlying date.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

`var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) to set your own format:

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

*(Also see the example at [jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats).)*

And as other have stated, you can use the utility function:

```
// Extract a date from a string value with a specified format.
$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, settings )
```

Comment: yes, just did that, but my problem is how to parse it. Maybe I can use .split('/') but what if user enters something like this 1.1.2013

Comment: @impeRAtoR Ah, ok, doesn't it work with `$.datepicker.parseDate` which extracts a date from a string value with a specified format?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, user is not able to enter . or , when datepicker is implemented

Comment: @impeRAtoR I'm not really following you here =) What is the expected output? What do you want to format to?

Comment: LOL,  I would like to compare two dates,to make sure that end date is bigger than start date